# SELECT name from table where name in array and value = 0 || 1 depending on name

Tags: postgresql

Im looking to get some data but the query is giving me trouble I have tried a lot of different things but cant seem to get it. The below info is simplified a lot but should give me the base for what I need.

```
table
id name value
0 config1 1
0 config2 0
1 config1 0
1 config2 0
2 config1 0
2 config2 1
3 config1 1
3 config2 1
```

so what I want to do is:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (name = 'config1' AND value = '1') AND (name = 'config2' AND value = '0')

the results I want to see are:

```
config1 1 (this is the only important one)
config2 0 (I don't really care to see this row either)
```

I basically only want the data for anything with the name config1 that has a value of 1 but only if config2 has a value of 0. NOTE: lets pretend I don't have access to id (its generated from another query and the query we are running is actually running on different DB's so the pairs are actually unique to each DB we can only ever have one config1 or one config2 per DB).

Comment: Your query isn't working because your WHERE condition is never applied across multiple rows simultaneously, but only across each row individually.  What you need is a correlated subquery or possibly a self-join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE name = 'config1' AND value = '1'
AND id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'config2' AND value = '0')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9bdef/3